# Create child class instance from parent class instance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

TL;DR: Python; I have Parent, Child classes. I have an *instance* of Parent class, `parent`. Can I make a Child class instance whose `super()` is `parent`?

Somewhat specific use case (workaround available) is as follows: I'd like to make an instance of Logger class (from Python `logging` module), with `_log` method overloaded. Methods like `logger.info` or `logger.error` call this method with a `level` specified as either `INFO` or `ERROR` etc., I'd like to replace this one method, touch nothing else, and make it all work seamlessly.

Here's some things that don't work (well):

- I can't *just* inherit from `logging.Logger` instance and overload this one method and constructor, because `Logger` instances tend to be created via a factory method, `logging.getLogger(name)`. So I can't just overload the constructor of the wrapper like:

```
class WrappedLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super().__init__(...)

    def _log(self, ...):
```

and expect it to all work OK.

- I could make a wrapper class, which provides the methods I'd like to call on the resulting instance, like `.info` or `.error` - but then I have to manually come up with all the cases. It also doesn't work well when the `_log` method is buried a few calls down the stack - there is basically no way to guarantee that any use of the *wrapped* class will call my desired `_log` method
- I can make a little kludge like so:

```py
class WrappedLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._parent = parent

    def _log(...): # overload

    def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        return getattr(self._parent, method_name)
```

now whenever I have an instance of this class, and call, say, `wrapped.info(...)`, it will retrieve the *parent* method of `info`, call it, which will then call `self._log` which in turn points to my wrapped instance. But this feels very ugly.

- Similarly, I could take a regular instance of `Logger` and manually swap out the method; this is maybe a bit less "clever", and less ugly than the above, but similarly underwhelming.

This question has been asked a few times, but in slightly different contexts, where other solutions were proposed. Rather than looking for a workaround, I'm interested in whether there is a native way of constructing a child class instance with the parent *instance* specified.

Related questions:

- [Create child class instances from parent class instance, and call parent methods from child class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943693/create-child-class-instances-from-parent-class-instance-and-call-parent-methods) - here effectively a workaround is suggested
- [Python construct child class from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921258/python-construct-child-class-from-parent) - here the parent *can* be created in the child's constructor

Comment: Your second version shouldn't be a subclass.

Comment: The `super()` isn't a different instance, it's just a way to call methods of the parent class on `self`, so you can bypass the local override.

Comment: @Barmar ok, but my question stands. Normally when overriding a child class constructor, I have the option to call the parent class constructor first. Can I somehow, instead, build a child class instance on top of an existing parent class? What is the least hacky way of doing it?

Comment: Do you mean "on top of an existing parent class **instance**"? Your constructor could take a parent instance as an argument, and copy all the attributes into the new instance. It will be a new instance, though. I suspect what you're really looking for is a way to change the class of the instance from `Parent` to `Child`, and that isn't really supported.

Comment: @Barmar - yes sorry you're right, I mean *instance* (can't edit). I'm trying to probe how deep down this rabbit hole I can go...

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to supply a custom logger class that is used by `getLogger`, you can "register" the custom class with the logging manager.

So, let's define a custom logger class

```py
from logging import Logger

class MyLogger(Logger):
    def _log(self, level, msg, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        print("my logger wants to log:", msg)
        super()._log(level, msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then we tell the global logging manager to use this class instead.

```py
from logging import setLoggerClass

setLoggerClass(MyLogger)
```

Thank you @Daniil Fajnberg, for pointing out, that `setLoggerClass` exists.

Now `getLogger` will instantiate your custom class.

```py
from logging import getLogger

logger = getLogger(__file__)

logger.error("Dummy Error")
```

This will log the error as normal and also print `"my logger wants to log: ..."`.

**Note:** The `_log` method you are overloading is *undocumented*. Maybe there is a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I wanted to suggest the same thing, but I think it would be better to use the public _and_ documented [`setLoggerClass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.setLoggerClass) function. :)

Comment: This works, thanks. My example is really more a motivation - I have a list of workarounds ready. Rather, I'm wondering the more general question: what's the least hacky way of creating a Child class instance (WrappedLogger) whose parent - instance of Parent / Logger is a given instance of Parent / Logger.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg oh, good point, how could i have missed that

Answer (score 1):

From the way you keep re-phrasing your more general question, it seems you misunderstand how object creation works. You are asking for a

> way of constructing a child class instance with the parent *instance* specified.

There is no such concept as a "parent instance". Inheritance refers to classes, not objects. This means you need to define yourself, what that term is supposed to mean. How would you define a "parent instance"? What should it be and when and how should it be created?

Just to demonstrate that there is no mechanism for creating "parent instances", when a child class instance is created, consider this:

```py
class Foo:
    instances = []

    def __new__(cls):
        print(f"{cls.__name__}.__new__()")
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        Foo.instances.append(instance)
        return instance

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

bar = Bar()

assert len(Foo.instances) == 1
assert Foo.instances[0] is bar
assert type(bar) is Bar
assert isinstance(bar, Foo)
```

The output is `Bar.__new__()` and obviously the assertions are passed. This goes to show that when we create an instance of `Bar` it delegates construction further up the MRO chain (because it doesn't implement its own `__new__` method), which results in a call to `Foo.__new__`. It creates the object (by calling `object.__new__`) and puts it into its `instances` list. `Foo` does *not* also create another instance of class `Foo`.

You also seem to misunderstand, what calling the [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) class does, so I suggest checking out the documentation. In short, it is just an elegant tool to access a related **class** (again: not an instance).

So, again, your question is ill defined.

If you mean (as @Barmar suggested) that you want a way to copy all the attributes of an instance of `Foo` over to an instance of `Bar`, that is another story. In that case, you still need to be careful to define, what exactly you mean by "all attributes".

Typically this would refer to the instances [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__). But do you also want its [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) copied? What about methods? Do you want them copied, too? And do you want to just replace everything on the `Bar` instance or only update those attributes set on the `Foo` instance?

I hope you see, what I am getting at. I guess the simplest way is just update the instances `__dict__` with values from the other one:

```py
...

class Bar(Foo):
    def update_from(self, obj):
        self.__dict__.update(obj.__dict__)

foo = Foo()
foo.n = 1
foo.text = "Hi"

bar = Bar()
bar.update_from(foo)

print(bar.n, bar.text)  # output: `1 Hi`
```

And you could of course do that in the `__init__` method of `Bar`, if you wanted. If the initialization of `Foo` is deterministic and instances keep the initial arguments laying around somewhere, you could instead just call the inherited `super().__init__` from `Bar.__init__` and pass those initial arguments to it from the instance. Something like this:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = x + y

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, foo_obj):
        super().__init__(foo_obj.x, foo_obj.y)

foo = Foo(2, 3)
bar = Bar(foo)
print(bar.z)  # output: `5`
```

I hope this makes things clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding correctly, what @Bennet wants is - he has some custom logger classes derived from Logger(Logger acts as interface) like Logger1, Logger2 etc(which implementation gets chosen will vary at runtime). On top of each of this he wants to add some functionality which modifies only the _log function of each of these implementations.

IMO there shouldn't be any direct way to do it, since what you are attempting is trying to modify(not extend) the behaviour of an existing class which is not recommended for OOP paradigm.
The hacky way is clever (found it cool).

```
def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        return getattr(self._parent,  method_name)
```

(I don't think you can do the same in Java)
P.S. Wanted to comment this but i am poor in SO it seems :)